# Best way to write the image file into folder from external link using PHP?

Tags: php

I need to store the 10000 images into folder from external link . So, I wrote the cron process  to execute the function .

```
In My cron file ,
 $img_file = file_get_contents($value1);
                $file_handler = fopen($file_loc,'w');
                if(fwrite($file_handler,$img_file)== false)
                {
                    echo 'error';
                }
                fclose($file_handler);
```

Its Working fine only 50 images . I Need to store more than 1000 images . fwrite is best way or not ? . Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

You probably get a time out on this script. Try incrementing the execution time limit: bool set_time_limit( int $seconds );

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: I have used max execution time in my cron file ;ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);

Comment: What time does this function return after setting the max_execution_time to -1? `echo ini_get('max_execution_time');`